# Is the null set $\emptyset$ a real subset of any set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My query is simple.

If $A=\{1,2,3\}$. the subsets of $A$ are $\{1,2,3\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}, \{1\},\{2\}, \{3\}, \{\}$.

As per the textbook, the subset $\{1,2,3\}$ is not a *Proper subset* of $A$ but the others like $\{1,2\}$ or $\{2\}$ (any subset containing any member) can be a Proper subset.

Now my question is the **null set**, $\{\}$ or $\emptyset$, a **Proper subset** of $A$?

And how can one count the **Proper subsets** of any set?

Comment: What is your textbook's definition of a "real subset"? (And what is your textbook?)

Comment: Possibly a translation problem? A **proper** subset of $A$ is a set $B$ with $B\subsetneq A$. With this definition $\emptyset$ is a proper subset of $A$ unless $A=\emptyset$

Comment: Or "real" means "non-trivial" here?

Comment: What language is your textbook in? Surely not English? As Hagen says, the correct term is _proper_ subset.

Comment: They wrote it real, but I think It should be proper. Thanks.

Comment: The term in English is *Proper*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A\neq \emptyset$ then $\emptyset$ is a real subset of $A$ (with the definition that $X$ is called a real subset of $A$, if $X\subseteq A$ but $X\neq A$).

For finite $A$ the corresponding formula is $2^n-1$. Note that this works for the empty set as-well, it has $0$ elements, hence $2^0-1=0$ real subsets.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Well explained. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Typically mathematicians operate with with three terms:

- subset
- **proper** subset
- **non-trivial** subset

Where **proper** typically excludes the full set, and **non-trivial** excludes the full set and the empty set. But other definitions are seen, and I don't recall ever having heard of **real subset** (If the full set was a set om complex numbers, I might interpret it as the intersection with $\mathbb R$), so it really depends on your book/what it should have been translated to.

Comment: Sorry, The term should be 'Proper'. Thanks